# Error after moving wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress

i was working on a wordpress blog under a test domain (example.com/blog/) and now i want to move it under its own domain which is on the same server but different vhost.

After googling a bit i found a way to do it by simply moving the files however this generated a 500 internal error.
This is (almost) normal because the site reads the old site location. I had to update it with the follwing code placed inside the `functions.php`

```
<?php
update_option('siteurl','http://example.com');
update_option('home','http://example.com');
?>
```

I tried with this code to reload the page cuple of times as the wordpress docs said but again nothing!

My server config:
Ubuntu 13
Nginx
MariaDB

Current location: /var/www/clients/client0/web3/web/arduino/
Desired location: /var/www/clients/client0/web7/web/

Any ideas on how to make it work?

**EDIT:** Im using ISPconfig to create virtual hosts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the database to make sure that in the options table the site url and home url are set to the correct locations.

Comment: It may have, the problem is 500 error have a lot of possible causes.